# Meir Einei Yisroel on כבוד שמים

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, kavod, chofetz-chaim

The Chofeitz Chayim says in *Meir Einei Yisroel* the following:

> "Why do we wait for Mashiach? Because we need parnassa, a cure for a disease, nachas from our children? Because someone in our family needs a shidduch? No! Hashem knows our innermost thoughts, and He says to us, 'I can send you those things without sending you Mashiach!' Instead, each one of us must cry for the lack of כבוד שמים - for the pain of the Shechinah in our exile, and then Mashiach will surely come."

Does anyone know where in Meir Einei Yisroel this is located?

Comment: As you probably expect us to ask: how do you know he writes this? Did you see this quoted somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: What makes you think that this quotation exists in Meir Einei Yisroel? Please [edit] to show the basis of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quote appears to be a word for word quote from [here](http://www.torahtavlin.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/44-Devarim.pdf). The source listed there is Sefer Meir Einei Yisroel (1:236); i.e. volume 1 (of 6) page 236.

Comment: @chiddushitorah As you have been asked repeatedly, please don't omit information from your questions. In this case, and in most cases, you are clearly quoting chunks of text from somewhere, yet you almost never tell us from where. Identifying the source often makes it much simpler to answer, as in this case where the source itself contained the answer.